# G Render is null in integration tests

Tags: spring, grails

I am getting the error below when I am running an integration test, and attempting to render a template.  The unique part of this is the template is rendering a template inside it on line 93.  The reason I am doing this is to have a template that I am rendering to convert it to a PDF, it contains a styling template that calls the view template.  Then the same view template I am using to set in a gsp page with styling for preview within the browser

The template containing the nested template is below minus the styling

```
<html>
<head>
<style  type="text/css" media="print"></style>
</head>
<body>
    <g:render template="depositStatement"/>
 </body>
 </html>
```

This works when running the application, but does not work when running integration tests.

```
Failure:  |
Print Deposit Request(com.srm.billing.BillingPaymentRequestControllerIntegrationSpec)
 |
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException: Error executing tag <g:render>: null
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPage.throwRootCause(GroovyPage.java:527)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPage.invokeTag(GroovyPage.java:470)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at C__Development_Grails36_sales_revenue_webapp_grails_app_views_billingPaymentRequest__printDepositStatement_gsp.run_closure1(_printDepositStatement.gsp:93)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:417)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.GroovyPageTagBody.executeClosure(GroovyPageTagBody.java:206)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.GroovyPageTagBody.captureClosureOutput(GroovyPageTagBody.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.GroovyPageTagBody.call(GroovyPageTagBody.java:219)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.SitemeshTagLib.captureTagContent(SitemeshTagLib.groovy:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.SitemeshTagLib$_closure3.doCall(SitemeshTagLib.groovy:157)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPage.invokeTagLibClosure(GroovyPage.java:501)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPage.invokeTag(GroovyPage.java:419)
    at C__Development_Grails36_sales_revenue_webapp_grails_app_views_billingPaymentRequest__printDepositStatement_gsp.run(_printDepositStatement.gsp:94)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPageWritable.doWriteTo(GroovyPageWritable.java:217)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPageWritable.writeTo(GroovyPageWritable.java:128)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPagesTemplateRenderer.makeTemplate(GroovyPagesTemplateRenderer.java:219)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPagesTemplateRenderer.render(GroovyPagesTemplateRenderer.java:105)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.RenderTagLib$_closure7.doCall(RenderTagLib.groovy:364)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPage.captureTagOutput(GroovyPage.java:586)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.TagLibraryMetaUtils.registerMethodMissingForTags_closure3(TagLibraryMetaUtils.groovy:55)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at com.srm.billing.BillingPaymentRequestService.renderOutput(BillingPaymentRequestService.groovy:656)
    at com.srm.billing.BillingPaymentRequestService.getOrCreateBillingDepositRequest(BillingPaymentRequestService.groovy:94)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
    at com.srm.billing.BillingPaymentRequestControllerIntegrationSpec.Print Deposit Request(BillingPaymentRequestControllerIntegrationSpec.groovy:73)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.hash(ConcurrentHashMap.java:333)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:988)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPagesTemplateRenderer.generateScaffoldedTemplate(GroovyPagesTemplateRenderer.java:248)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPagesTemplateRenderer.access$300(GroovyPagesTemplateRenderer.java:64)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPagesTemplateRenderer$1$1.updateValue(GroovyPagesTemplateRenderer.java:164)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPagesTemplateRenderer$1$1.updateValue(GroovyPagesTemplateRenderer.java:135)
    at grails.util.CacheEntry.getValue(CacheEntry.java:141)
    at grails.util.CacheEntry.getValue(CacheEntry.java:81)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPagesTemplateRenderer.findAndCacheTemplate(GroovyPagesTemplateRenderer.java:132)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPagesTemplateRenderer.render(GroovyPagesTemplateRenderer.java:100)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.RenderTagLib$_closure7.doCall(RenderTagLib.groovy:364)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPage.invokeTagLibClosure(GroovyPage.java:501)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPage.invokeTag(GroovyPage.java:419)
    ... 36 more
|Completed 3 integration tests, 1 failed in 0m 3s
```

Comment: Can you put your test code snippet??

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't mean render tag is null, your gsp has null pointer exception, so check your second gsp for possible NPE. Just to verify its not render tag issue, you can remove every thing from your second gsp and that should fix it, which will prove render is not an issue, and then find out the cause of NPE